# Question on differentiability $f''(u).(h,k)$?

Tags: calculus, analysis, derivatives

if i have a function $f$ and $E$ a space then $f':E\rightarrow E^*$ and we note $f'(u).h$ so what about $f''$ how it's defined ? why we note $f''(u).(h,k)$ ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

A very short answer: 
$f''(u)(h,k)$ is the result of differentiating $f'(u)h$ with respect to $u$ along the variation $k$. This notation is related to the canonical isometry between $L(X,L(X,Y))$ and $L_2(X\times X,Y)$, the space of continuous bilinear mappings.
For more details, you can read *A primer of nonlinear analysis* by A. Ambrosetti and G. Prodi, or *Differential calculus and its applications* by M. J. Field.

Comment: so $f'':E\rightarrow (E,E^*)^*$ RIGHT ?

Comment: Yes, since $f \colon E \to \mathbb{R}$.